# Help with generating ical ics files

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, icalendar

I would like to generate ics files. Are there any libraries or APIs that would be of help please? Thank you

Comment: I saw your tag #icalendar, and I read #icelander, and I was wondering why those guys get to get their own tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [libical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/) can do it?  If it can't, I'd look to see if some other language (php, ruby, whatever) has an iCal generator, and then translate it to Objective-C.

Comment: Thank you. This seems like the best out there. Now I just need to figure out how to get it working!